# Zeoslib new version encoding problem, strange charaters

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, delphi-10.2-tokyo, zeos

I have installed Zeoslib 7.2.4 because of updating to Delphi 10.2 and after testing my projects the result of SELECT isn't expected. The previous version 7.1.4 Works fine.

The results after updating to 7.2.4:

[image: Worst results]

Connection `ClientCodePage` is `binary`. If I change this to `utf8` the results will look like this, The `Address` col is correct but `Title` is still corrupted:

[image: Better result]

The database and table collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`. I don't have a problem with version 7.1.4. One workaround for this problem is this:

```
TEncoding.Default.GetString(DBQuery.FieldByName('Title').AsBytes)
```

This is the expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: I don't get it, you say that your table collation is swedish, but your expected result is arabian ?.

Comment: By the way, what is the encoding of the database ?.

Comment: @MarcGuillot, As you know the default collation is latin1_swedish_ci (this is the reason) and my program WORKS before (the image isn't fake, it's the old program), and about your second question : "The database and table collation is latin1_swedish_ci"

Comment: @MarcGuillot, Unfortunately the program is currently using by customers and I'm looking for a solution rather than changing the DB properties.

Comment: The encoding and the collation set are two different things. The encoding defines the byte codes that correspond to every character (utf-8, iso8859-1, ..) while the collation set defines the sort order of those characters, which usually depends on your language. It seems to me that you need to found which encoding is defined on your database, and set the same on Zeos.

Comment: Looks like the default CodePage has changed from Zeos 7.1.4 to Zeos  7.2.4.

Comment: You also say "update to Delphi 10.2", what did you use before?

Comment: Zeoslib 7.1.4 with XE6